# Putty: remote my server from my home

Tags: putty

There is a server in my company and many people in the company work on it by Putty. We installed the Putty for our own computers to remote the server. BUT all of these happened in the company's inner web.

Now I want to remote the server from outer web. For example, I am home and I work on the company's server. For now I dont know how to realize this.

How can I configure the server and my PC at home?
Need I make some configuration for the router of the company? How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am sorry I am new here. What's the difference between Super User and off-topic??

Comment: Your question is off-topic for StackOverflow, see what questions are [on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question would better fit on Super User. See what is [on-topic there](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your company has a competent IT staff, there is a firewall that blocks incoming SSH attempts out. (It is called SSH, not Putty. Putty is just a program that Windows users tend to use for SSH.) Inside the company's network, you can SSH. So, from home, you will hit a firewall and you can't SSH in.

Does your company have a VPN system? If so, use that. There are many forms of VPN. Your company's IT staff can tell you how to configure your home machine so it can connect to the company's VPN. Once it does that, it will be as though your home computer is inside the company. You are inside the firewall. You can SSH.

You can ask if they will open the firewall for you. They shouldn't, but you can ask.

If you don't have VPN, all is not lost, but it gets more difficult. I don't expect you to do this, so I will only list the steps.

1. Install an SSH server on your home computer. Get it up and running. SSH into it from another computer at home.
2. Forward incoming port 22 requests to your home's firewall/router to your home computer so you can SSH into your home machine from outside your house, ie: From work. Test it from work to ensure it works.
3. Set up a reverse port forward SSH connection from the server at work to your home computer. What this does is initiate an SSH connection from the work server to your home computer. It then listens on a port on your home computer (pretend you used 2222 as the port). Now, from home, you SSH to your home computer (localhost) on 2222 and it connects over the previously made connection to the server at work.
4. Your IT staff might notice that you did this. They probably won't like it because you are bypassing their firewall.

Comment: We have no VPN for now. Could we make our server as a VPN? Or I must have another computer as a VPN?

Comment: You need a VPN server that is accessible through the firewall. So, you cannot do it. The administrators must do it. They can open a firewall rule specifically for your IP address, but likely won't. Because I don't use Windows, I usually use the option of reverse SSH. I have no clue how to set up an SSH server in Windows or even if it can be done for free. If you can set up an SSH server on your home machine, do that. Then, ask if you need help with the rest of the steps for setting up reverse SSH.

Comment: thanks a lot. I ve learnt a lot from you. I will discuss with my collègues to decide what we do.

Answer (score 1):

You can either forward the port of the server to the public internet, or you can set up a VPN located inside your company's LAN that can be reached from outside the LAN such as [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/).

**Note**: If you are planning to forward the server directly, make sure the server's security settings are set up correctly to prevent misuse of attackers. You can also restrict access to specific IP addresses using a firewall.

Comment: I am considering restricting some specific IP. But I dont know how the family-web works. I mean does a family web have its own IP address? For example I have internet at home, and there is ONLY ONE computer at home, Does it mean that my computer has the unique IP address? Or this IP address is only the IP of some upper router?

Comment: In my house, there is a router and a computer. If I google "my ip address", some webs could tell me my IP address. Does I use this IP alone? Or I share this IP with other guys just like an inner web? If I use this IP alone, I think this gonna be safe even if I dont use VPN but restrict some IP in the server.

Comment: @Thomas Most home networks have a dynamically allocated ip address, which changes every few days. What you can do is set up a dynamic hostname that is constant, but redirects to your ip, even if it changes. If you're using IPv4, all computers behind your router at home share the same public ip.

Comment: "set up a dynamic hostname that is constant, but redirects to your ip" how to do this?

Comment: @Thomas [no-ip](https://www.noip.com) is a popular service that provides a dynamic hostname for you to use. If your router supports it, you can let it update your hostname automatically. If not, you have to run an update client on any pc in your LAN to send the most up-to-date ip address to the service. You can use an optional CNAME record on an existing or new domain to customize the hostname to your liking if you prefer to have one in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your server is behind corporate network, you MUST require a VPN connection to access it. Talk to your IT department and they will be able to help with setting VPN connection.